# Recording iPhone screen (iOS 11.4) using QuickTime on macOS 10.13.4

Tags: iphone, ios, quicktime

I launch QuickTime, select **New Screen Recording**, select my iPhone from the practically hidden dropdown list of sources

[image]

Nothing shows up (don't remember what it use to do). I click the red button and the window disappears into the menu bar and for a few moments QuickTime is locked up. If it comes back I click stop but there is no screen capture.

How do I get this to work again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you are looking for is **New Movie Recording**.

[image]

To record iPhone screen:

1. Select New Movie Recording.
2. Click on the dropdown besides the red circular record button.
3. Select iPhone under Camera (and Microphone if required).
4. Hit the record button.
5. Voila! you are recording your iPhone's screen now!
6. Once done, hit stop and save the recording at the desired location on your Mac. Note that the recording is saved on disk on Mac and **not** in the iPhone.

[image]

Comment: "New Movie Recording" does not give me options to capture the screen. It only gives me options to use the iPhone's camera and microphone

Comment: The terminology is misleading. When selecting iPhone under Camera, you are not choosing to record via iPhone camera but recording the iPhone screen.